# Removing items from an arraylist that contains subclass and superclass items

Tags: java

I have an arraylist 'items' which contains items from a superclass as well as items from its subclass.

```
    for (Item item : items)
    {
        if (item.getLocation() == location)
        {   
            System.out.println(item.getDescription() + " is in this location");
            if (item instanceof Monster)
            {
                Monster monster = (Monster)item; 
                if (monster.hasDied())
                {
                    System.out.println(monster.getDescription() + " has been defeated!");
                    items.remove(monster);     
                }
            }   
        }   
    }
```

I am trying to remove the monster from the arraylist if it is found that the monster has died. All of the methods are working and I am aware that you cannot remove items from an arraylist while in a foreach loop as shown above. I previously used the code below to remove the monster from the arraylist, however this was when there was a separate 'items' and 'monsters' arraylist. They are now both in the same 'items' arraylist as the 'Monster' class is a subclass of the 'Item' class.

```
    Iterator<Monster> iter = monsters.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) 
    {
        Monster monster = iter.next();
        if (monster.hasDied())
        {
            if (monster.getLocation() == location)
            {
                System.out.println(monster.getDescription() + " has been defeated!");
                iter.remove();
            }
            else
            {
               iter.remove(); 
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there anyway I could adapt either approach to remove the specified monster from the arraylist?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: what's wrong with the second solution, with the iterator?

Comment: instance of and typecast to monster in the second option should work. But its not good design.

Comment: Why not use an `Iterator<Item>` and combine both codes?

Comment: You could combine the 2 solutions: check type in the iteration cycle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely - all you need to do is combining the two approaches that you have:

- Iterate the list using `Iterator` the way you do it in the second approach;
- check for the current `item` to be a `Monster` the way you do it in the first approach. This combination would let you find the `Monster`, and `remove` it using the iterator.

Here is how you can do that:

```
Iterator<Item> iter = items.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) 
{
    Item item = iter.next();
    if (item instanceof Monster)
    {
        Monster monster = (Monster)item; 
        if (monster.hasDied())
        {
            if (monster.getLocation() == location)
            {
                System.out.println(monster.getDescription() + " has been defeated!");
                iter.remove();
            }
            else
            {
               iter.remove(); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Absolutely (+1), of course its a bit nasty. If monster and item really are to be used differently then really they should be held seperately, while instanceof is occationally useful it is often a sign of bad code. I would either; hold the monsters in a seperate arraylist (possibly in addition to the main items arraylist) or give all items a isStillValid() method and getNoLongerValidText() methods. (some items may always return true for isStillValid(), but perhaps items that are used up may return false)

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone. Yes they were held as separate arraylists, however it is an exercise I am working through and it asked for the two to be held in the same arraylist (I'm assuming for learning purposes - to learn about specialisation?). Thanks again!

Comment: @RichardTingle I agree, if `Monsters` and everything else are used differently, then they should be in different collections. However, it looks like the OP has started in that way, but decided to depart from that approach later for reasons we don't know.

Comment: @user2120977 I understand, yes in that case either dasblinkenlight's instanceof method or giving all items an isStillValid() method (overridden by Monster) will satisfy your requirements

Comment: @user2120977 I've included my own answer showing how my alternative would work

Answer (score 1):

A Polymorphic method, that avoids type checking would be as follows. In this method it doesn't matter if a particular `Item` is a `Monster` because all `Item`s can be checked for validity and the `Item` itself knows what it do if it isn't valid

```
public class Item {
    //assorted item methods


    public boolean isStillValid(){
        return true; //by default items remain valid
    }

    public String getDescription(){
        return "SomeItem"; //I assume you can provide a better description than this, I don't know your usage case so can't comment
    }

    public String getNoLongerValidText(){
        return getDescription() + "is no longer valid"; //items that actually become invalid should override this and give a better text
    }
}
```

```
public class Monster extends Item{

    //assorted extra Monster Methods

    int health=100;

    public boolean isStillAlive(){
        if (health<=0){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isStillValid() {
        return isStillAlive();
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return "MonsterName";
    }

    @Override
    public String getNoLongerValidText() {
        return getDescription() + "has died";
    }

}
```

Because all items can be checked for validity, it no longer matters if a particular `Item` is a `Monster`

```
Iterator<Item> iter = items.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) 
{
    Item item = iter.next();
    if (item.isStillValid()==false)
    {
        System.out.println(item.getNoLongerValidText());
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```

This is particularly nice because it scales well when other `Item`s (eg potions (`Potion extends Item`) that have only a certain number of uses) can also become invalid.

Comment: Thanks Richard, that's some really informative information and a nice solution.

Comment: This is the more correct solution in my oppinion. Instance of and typecasting is not good design. This is.

Answer (score 0):

As you know, you cannot remove items while iterating the collection. So what you can do is create a list(lets call it toRemoveObjList) of objects you want to remove while iterating and checking their status. Once you are finished with the iteration, you should be having a list of all the objects need to be removed. Then simply call

```
list.removeAll(toRemoveObjList);
```

For your reference, javadocs for removeAll(Collection c)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#removeAll(java.util.Collection)

Comment: I'm not at all sure this is true, I believe the iterator.remove() method is explictly for this purpose

Comment: What @RichardTingle says is correct, or at least `iterator.remove()` supports it. However, I think it is an equally good solution to collect items to remove as proposed. I don't really like using `Iterator`.

Comment: True its a perfectly reasonable thing to do, but in all cases (apart from perhaps the enhanced for loop) you can remove as you iterate, in a traditional for you go through the indicies backwards and with an iterator you use the .remove() method

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what are you trying to achieve, but why you won't simply write it this way:

```
    for (Iterator<Item> iter = items.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
            Item item = iter.next();
            if (item instanceof Monster) {
                    Monster monster = (Monster) item;
                    if (monster.hasDied()) {
                        if (monster.getLocation() == location) {
                            System.out.println(monster.getDescription() + " has been defeated!");
                        }
                        iter.remove();
                    }
            }
     }
```

Comment: The OP has all their items (`Item` class and `Monster extends Item` class) all in the same class, as such they can't just get an `Iterator<Monster>`